# How WP decide to show or not to show in admin panel the pop-up window with hint? Need a fix

Tags: mysql, dashboard

To all newcommers the WP3.5 show the floating hint about new abilities of 3.5 version placed on top left coner of screen saying:

**We’ve combined the admin bar and the old Dashboard header into one
persistent toolbar. Hover over the toolbar items to see what’s new. {close}**

after close-click the hint disapeared for good. And this was my case. but after use of Search&Replace plugin on my mysql database i got this banner again, and this time it is not clicable and still atached to top left corner unless i change screen for other wordpress activity i.e. apearance or something other than initial dashboard. I wonder where i do look for fix in database? I joined a screenshot of this banner (ru_RU)

[WP3.5 non-removable hint http://u.askdev.ru/50e/f00b/e4df3b/medium.gif](http://u.askdev.ru/50e/f00b/e4df3b/medium.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dismissed pointers are stored as user meta, you can inspect this for yourself with:

```
$meta = get_user_meta( wp_get_current_user() );
print_r( $meta['dismissed_wp_pointers'] );
```

In your case, the meta might be empty or damaged, to update dismissed pointers for ALL users on your blog, you could run this function (only once):

```
function wpse80084_dismiss_wp_pointers()
{
    $dismissed = array( 'wp330_toolbar','wp330_media_uploader','wp330_saving_widgets','wp340_choose_image_from_library' );
    $dismissed = implode( ',', $dismissed );
    $users = get_users();
    foreach ( $users as $user )
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'dismissed_wp_pointers', $dismissed );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse80084_dismiss_wp_pointers' );
```

Comment: Great, SOLVED with your aid. I just looked at user_meta and found  that my user had only _dismissed_wp_pointers wp350_media_ so as advised i changed the value to correct one I did it in slightly different manner - installed a new blog and then copy-pasted the dismissed_wp_pointers value in phpmyadmin all these 
wp330_toolbar,wp330_saving_widgets,wp340_choose_image_from_library,wp340_customize_current_theme_link,wp350_media